# get post type plural

Tags: custom-post-types, api, labels

Currently I'm trying to get the post type labels plural. In detail:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_post_types'][ get_current_screen()->post_type ]->labels->name
```

This is how I'm trying to retrieve it - in the admin UI - using the public wp API functions:

```
$post_type_name = get_current_screen()->post_type;
$post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type_name );
get_post_type_labels( $post_type_obj );
```

The result is the following Error:

> `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\development\xampp\htdocs\wp_inst\wp-includes\post.php on line 1209`

The problem is that the post type objects labels is also an object, while `get_post_type_labels()` calls `_get_custom_object_labels()` internally and seems to expect an array.

Fun are the last two lines of the `_get_custom_object_labels()` function:

```
$labels = array_merge( $defaults, $object->labels );
return (object)$labels;
```

So, am I using the wrong functions? Is the core function wrong? Is this core function only meant to be used during custom post type registration?

---

*Note: Currently on WP version 3.3.2.*

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the best / correct way to do it is, but I've definitely seen this exact same behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Edit:

get_post_type_labels was never intended to be a public function.  It is only used internally when registering a post type.  See these trac tickets:

- [get_taxonomy_labels() and _get_custom_object_labels() fail if $object->taxonomy is not array](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16310)
- [Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /.../wp-includes/post.php on line 1202](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18257)

---

Like you mentioned in your question you can get the labels directly from the globals:

```
function c3m_get_labels() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $post_type_name = get_current_screen ()->post_type;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->labels;
    return $labels;
}
```

Running the function:

```
$labels = c3m_get_labels();
    var_dump($labels);
```

Returns:

```
object(stdClass)[232]
  public 'name' => string 'Posts' (length=5)
  public 'singular_name' => string 'Post' (length=4)
  public 'add_new' => string 'Add New' (length=7)
  public 'add_new_item' => string 'Add New Post' (length=12)
  public 'edit_item' => string 'Edit Post' (length=9)
  public 'new_item' => string 'New Post' (length=8)
  public 'view_item' => string 'View Post' (length=9)
  public 'search_items' => string 'Search Posts' (length=12)
  public 'not_found' => string 'No posts found.' (length=15)
  public 'not_found_in_trash' => string 'No posts found in Trash.' (length=24)
  public 'parent_item_colon' => null
  public 'all_items' => string 'All Posts' (length=9)
  public 'menu_name' => string 'Posts' (length=5)
  public 'name_admin_bar' => string 'Post'
```

Alternate use without needing global $wp_post_types:

```
function c3m_get_labels() {
    $post_type_name = get_current_screen ()->post_type;
    $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object ( $post_type_name );
    return $post_type_obj;
}
```

Running the function:

```
$labels = c3m_get_labels();
    $labels = $labels->labels;
    var_dump($labels);
```

After doing several tests I have concluded that it is impossible to use get_post_type_labels passing the $post_type_object as [specified in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_labels).  So it seems the only use for `get_post_type_labels` is internally in core when a post type is registered.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I updated the Codex and hope the ticket goes in. Marked as solution, +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This works...

```
$object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );

echo $object->labels->name;
echo $object->label;

// returns plural name = posts

// var_dump ( $object ); to return all items within the object
// In this instance you can access anything within the class by `$object-> ??? -> ???`
```

This works...

```
$object = get_post_type_object( 'post' )->labels;

echo $object->name;

// returns plural name = posts
// in this instance you have access to the labels array only within the object
```

This works too (but why would you bother...)

```
$post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( 'post' )->labels;
$object = get_post_type_labels( $post_type_obj );

echo $object->name;

// returns plural name = posts
```

This also works,

```
$post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
$object = get_post_type_labels( $post_type_obj->labels );   

echo $object->name;

// returns plural name = posts
```

...and does prove that it is entirely possible to use `get_post_type_labels` in themes/plugins passing the `post_type_object` but as I've been saying the Codex does not tell you to specify what `->attributes` within the object you want to access, hence you receive the error;

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\post.php on line 1209`

Wrapping your code into a function is also a solution should your use-case permit or warrant that.

Any of the above is perfectly acceptable whether its in a function or not, they are still performing the same mechanics and are susceptible to the same problems if the core were to change.

Comment: No, that outputs the mentioned error. You don't even have to `echo` to crash your installation :)

Comment: Passing `$post_type_object` to `get_post_type_labels` will not work being that you are trying to pass a class object as an array, so by dropping `get_post_type_labels` you can just pluck what you want from the object directly.

Comment: I understand your thoughts. As you can see from the Q, I already know where I can get it directly from the globals, but that's not what I'm after. I just want to know why the hell there's an API function in core, that doesn't work with the way core builds his globals, but still tries to retrieve it from the global... Anyway +1 for your effort :)

Comment: I've updated both my answers. Notice the change in **option 1** where we need to specify the array within the object we want to pass to `get_post_type_labels` because that function expects an array and not an object. But using **option 2** you eliminate an entire line of code. In both instances we are using built in WP functions so I'm not sure what you meant by getting it directly from the globals.

Comment: I expect an API function let me get back a result without hitting subproperties. Else I could go with this: `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types'][ get_current_screen()->post_type ]->labels->name` and get the same output without errors. So something in core is _simply wrong_.

Comment: With the last update (Option 3), you're setting `$post_type_obj = $post_type_name`, which won't work. And with `Correct = get_post_type_labels( $post_type_obj->labels );`, you're calling the labels from the object, with ... well, _the labels_! :) (Don't know how much sense it makes stuffing something into an API function and then retrieving exactly what you throwed in).

Comment: Point with using the `return` value from one core API function as `$input` for another core API function is, that the internal naming and structure for me as the end user doesn't matter. If it changes, it's ok, as my code won't crash - the sending and retrieving functions care about that.

Comment: As you've seen from the questions bottom note, I'm not really behind _how_ to do it with globals, but more about _if the API doesn't provide what I tried to_, so I didn't mark yours as solution (but upvote). Some notes aside: The 1st one is equal to targeting the global directly. The 2nd one is mixture out of globals and API functions. With the 3rd and 4th one, you're throwing the labels into the API fn ... to get the labels back :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of different event types and wanted to display the event type next to each title in the loop, so I made a very minor modification to userabuser's code:

```
$object = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() )->labels;
echo $object->name;
```

So my complete code now looks like this:

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php $object = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() )->labels;
echo $object->name; ?></h3>
```

And it works just fine. After each title it displays a hyphen and the plural event type.